# Best way to do authorisation through REST API using Lumen?

Tags: json, api, rest, authorization, lumen

I am making a simple REST API using latest stable version of Lumen. That API is going to be used in mobile applications, and there is one thing I'm not sure about.

What is the best ( secure enough ) way to an authorization? At the moment I am doing a simple `POST` request to the server url like `http://api.example.com/v1/auth` with `username` and `password` parameters and return a JSON response like
`{ "code" : 200, "message" : "OK", "access_token" : string }`
or
`{ "code" : 401, "message" : "Unauthorized" }`

- Is JSON response a good solution?
- Is it better to return response code within header?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked this? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/183665/the-best-way-to-implement-authorization-for-a-rest-api
2. 200 and 401 seem the "standard" response to me.